# How to delete .eslintcache file in react?

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to React. I have a problem I can not solve. I have an ".eslintcache" file, which was created for me automatically as soon as I created a new app in React using "create-react-app". I do not know why I have this file. I tried to delete it but it always comes back.
I ran this command - "npm uninstall -g eslint --save" - to delete eslint's directory but it does not help.
I do not know how to handle it, I did not find a solution to it, I would be happy to help.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is part of the new version in react. I also had files "reportWebVitals" and "setupTests", I deleted them and everything works properly.

With "reportWebVitals" you can track real user performance on your site.
And with "setupTests" you are Initializing Test Environment

this feature is available with react-scripts@4.0.0 and higher

I do not need these properties, just deleted them and that's it, the eslintcache can not be deleted is part of the bundle.

Answer (score 39):

It seems as new issue in React App ([this issue opened on Nov 27, 2020](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/10161))

Put `.eslintcache` in `.gitignore` also do:

```
git rm -rf --cached .eslintcache
git add .
```

`git rm`: remove files from working tree ...

`-r`: recursive removal in case of a directory name ...

`-f` or `-force`: Override the up-to-date check.

Details: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rm

Answer (score 38):

It is part of the CRA bundle. I'd recommend just adding it to the `.gitignore` file if it isn't in there already.

From the [ESLint docs](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/command-line-interface#caching):

> Store the info about processed files in order to only operate on the changed ones. The cache is stored in .eslintcache by default. Enabling this option can dramatically improve ESLint's running time by ensuring that only changed files are linted.

Comment: It's good to mention that this fix is temporary, as the create-react-app team recently made some work to move the .eslintcache file under the node_modules/.cache folder, which can be followed on this [pull-request](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/pull/9977) and this [issue](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/10161). Until the 4.0.2 is released, you better add it to your `.gitignore` and be careful of any ESLint errors not being updated in the `.eslintcache` (see [this issue comment](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/10161#issuecomment-737065960))

Answer (score 9):

This file is part of the new version of create-react-app package, you can't avoid it to be added, just like other files being added. This is the bundle.

Comment: Yes, from version 4.0.0.

Comment: i had two more files that was added "reportWebVitals" and "setupTests" - do i need them? i deleted them - this id the first time i saw those files

Comment: Don't just delete things, read about them before you delete.

Answer (score 2):

I faced the problem, tried putting `.eslintcache` in `.gitignore` and implement the command `git add .`  but was not enough, because you should do `git add .` after every change in your code, and that's not sence at all of course,  this is not a clean workround anyway.

So, simply i downgraded the `react-scripts` to `@4.0.0`, and that problem disapeared completely
I think the `react-scripts@4+` isn't stable yet

Answer (score 2):

I ended up writing a custom plugin to delete the `.eslintcache` before each watch compile:

```js
var exec = require("child_process").execSync;

module.exports = class ESLintClearPlugin {
  constructor(options) {
    this.options = options;
  }
  apply(compiler) {
    compiler.hooks.watchRun.tap("ESLintClearPlugin", () => {
      exec("del .eslintcache");
    });
  }
};
```

Then you use it in your webpack config:

```js
const ESLintClearPlugin = require("./pathtofile");
// webpack config    
plugins: [new ESLintClearPlugin()]
```