# eslintcache gets automatically uploaded to github, how to prevent it?

Tags: git, github, gitignore

when uploading something to my Git hub repository, this '.eslintcache' gets also there, what it is and how to put this to '.gitignore' ? just copy pasting its name there ?

Comment: Did you try that? Or research around how to remove files and folders from your repo generally?

Comment: @jonrsharpe it is not convenient to remove it everytime, i'm just not sure how to prevent it

Comment: You don't have to remove it every time, remove it once then ignore further changes.

Comment: everytime i upload react files to github, that file gets uploaded also

Comment: Then you *haven't* removed it from your repo and ignored further changes, but it's unclear what exactly you *have* done so we can't say what you did wrong.

Comment: This file is part of the new version of create-react-app package, so it cant be avoided to be added

Comment: That's not true, you can absolutely avoid adding it. Even without listing it in `.gitignore` you could *not add or stage it* - just don't do `git add .`, be specific about the changes you're including.

Comment: here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65079558/how-to-delete-eslintcache-file-in-react just dont know how to add it to gitignore, dont want to make mistake

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65415118/3001761

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I configure git to ignore some files locally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1753070/how-do-i-configure-git-to-ignore-some-files-locally)